# C# Type Troubles - WPF Controlling a Main Window

Tags: c#, inheritance, mvvm, types

I'm working on a project that presents a different main window to a user based on his/her role. There are three roles: Student, Trainer, and Admin. Even though the main window will be different for each role, I want to be able to call MainWindow.close() when the user logs out, regardless of the subtype of MainWindow.

I run into trouble in my switch statement when I try to assign a subtype of my MainWindow class (like AdminMainWindow) to my mainWindow variable which is typed as the super type MainWindow.

Please let me know how I might set up my class hierarchy to make this work.

```
namespace MVVM
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        LoginWindowViewModel loginWindowViewModel
        LoginWindow loginWindow; 

        MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel
        MainWindow mainWindow;

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            setUpNewLoginWindow();
        }

        void setUpNewLoginWindow()
        { 
            loginWindowViewModel = new LoginWindowViewModel();

            loginWindowViewModel.UserIsAuthenticated += new EventHandler<LoginSuccessfulEventArgs>(loginWindowViewModel_UserIsAuthenticated);

            loginWindow = new LoginWindow(loginWindowViewModel);

            loginWindow.Show();
        }

        void loginWindowViewModel_UserIsAuthenticated(object sender, LoginSuccessfulEventArgs e)
        {
            User authenticatedUser = e.AuthenticatedUser;

            switch (authenticatedUser.Role)
            {
                case "A":
                    mainWindowViewModel = new AdminMainWindowViewModel(authenticatedUser);
                    mainWindow = new AdminMainWindow(adminMainWindowViewModel);
                    break;

                case "S":
                    mainWindowViewModel = new StudentMainWindowViewModel(authenticatedUser);
                    mainWindow = new StudentMainWindow(studentMainWindowViewModel);
                    break;

                case "T":
                    mainWindowViewModel = new TrainerMainWindowViewModel(authenticatedUser);
                    mainWindow = new TrainerMainWindow(trainerMainWindowViewModel);
                    break;

                default:
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This user does not have a role assigned.");
                    break;
            }

            mainWindow.Show();

            mainWindowViewModel.UserIsNotAuthenticated += new EventHandler(mainWindowViewModel_UserIsNotAuthenticated);

            loginWindowViewModel = null;

            loginWindow.Close();
        }

        void mainWindowViewModel_UserIsNotAuthenticated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setUpNewLoginWindow();

            mainWindowViewModel = null;

            mainWindow.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

**** Comment on Solution ****

What I was trying to do was create Windows and ViewModels specific to the role of the user signing in, but then once I've constructed those objects, I wanted to treat them all the same so that I can have the App class listen to their 'user is unauthenticated event' and close the window - regardless of the type of ViewModel and Window that I happened to create in any particular instance of the app. Thanks, Connell.

**** Revised Code ****

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using MVVM.Model;
using MVVM.Utility;
using MVVM.View.MainWindowsByRole;
using MVVM.ViewModel;

namespace MVVM
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        LoginWindowViewModel loginWindowViewModel;
        LoginWindow loginWindow;

        MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel;
        Window mainWindow;

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            setUpNewLoginWindow();
        }

        void setUpNewLoginWindow()
        {
            loginWindowViewModel = new LoginWindowViewModel();

            loginWindowViewModel.UserIsAuthenticated += new EventHandler<LoginSuccessfulEventArgs>(loginWindowViewModel_UserIsAuthenticated);

            loginWindow = new LoginWindow(loginWindowViewModel);

            loginWindow.Show();
        }

        void loginWindowViewModel_UserIsAuthenticated(object sender, LoginSuccessfulEventArgs e)
        {
            User authenticatedUser = e.AuthenticatedUser;

            switch (authenticatedUser.Role)
            {
                case "A":
                    AdminMainWindowViewModel adminVM = new AdminMainWindowViewModel(authenticatedUser);
                    AdminMainWindow adminWindow = new AdminMainWindow(adminVM);
                    adminWindow.Show();
                    mainWindowViewModel = adminVM;
                    mainWindow = adminWindow;
                    break;

                case "S":
                    StudentMainWindowViewModel studentVM = new StudentMainWindowViewModel(authenticatedUser);
                    StudentMainWindow studentWindow = new StudentMainWindow(studentVM);
                    studentWindow.Show();
                    mainWindowViewModel = studentVM;
                    mainWindow = studentWindow;
                    break;

                case "T":
                    TrainerMainWindowViewModel trainerVM = new TrainerMainWindowViewModel(authenticatedUser);
                    TrainerMainWindow trainerWindow = new TrainerMainWindow(trainerVM);
                    trainerWindow.Show();
                    mainWindowViewModel = trainerVM;
                    mainWindow = trainerWindow;
                    break;

                default:
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This user does not have a role assigned.");
                    break;
            }

            mainWindowViewModel.UserIsNotAuthenticated += new EventHandler(mainWindowViewModel_UserIsNotAuthenticated);

            loginWindowViewModel = null;

            loginWindow.Close();
        }

        void mainWindowViewModel_UserIsNotAuthenticated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            setUpNewLoginWindow();

            mainWindowViewModel = null;

            mainWindow.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you exactly running into issues? Given the code it looks like you are only assigning `mainWindow` when the user is authenticated?

Comment: With case 'A' in the switch statement - I get an error when I construct a new AdminMainWindow and assign it to the mainWindow variable. The error I get is that the compiler cannot implicitly convert an AdminMainWindow object to a MainWindow object. AdminMainWindow inherits from MainWindow. 

Maybe I should cast AdminMainWindow object I'm creating to a MainWindow object so I can store it in the variable? But I thought maybe I wouldn't need to do that because of inheritance. I'm sure its something I don't understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
case "S":
    mainWindowViewModel = new StudentMainWindowViewModel(authenticatedUser);
    mainWindow = new StudentMainWindow(studentMainWindowViewModel);
    break;
```

performs an implicit widening conversion from StudentMainWindowViewModel to MainWindowViewModel. The problem is that you then try to use an implicit cast for the narrowing conversion in the next line. The StudentMainWindow constructor expects a StudentMainWindowViewModel but you pass in a MainWindowViewModel.

Please see this documentation for a better explanation.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1e94s7e(v=vs.140).aspx

This will also be informative.

[Converting between types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9352535/converting-between-types)

You could get away with it by modifying your code like this:

```
switch (authenticatedUser.Role)
        {
            case "A":
                AdminMainWindowViewModel adminVM = new AdminMainWindowViewModel(authenticatedUser);
                mainWindowViewModel = adminVM;
                mainWindow = new AdminMainWindow(adminVM);
                break;

            case "S":
                StudentMainWindowViewModel studentVM = new StudentMainWindowViewModel(authenticatedUser);
                mainWindowViewModel = studentVM;
                mainWindow = new StudentMainWindow(studentVM);
                break;

            case "T":
                TrainerMainWindowViewModel trainerVM = new TrainerMainWindowViewModel(authenticatedUser);
                mainWindowViewModel = trainerVM;
                mainWindow = new TrainerMainWindow(trainerVM);
                break;

            default:
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("This user does not have a role assigned.");
                break;
        }
```

Alternatively you could use an explicit cast:

```
case "A":
    mainWindowViewModel = new AdminMainWindowViewModel(authenticatedUser);
    mainWindow = new AdminMainWindow((AdminMainWindowViewModel)mainWindowViewModel);
    break;
```

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think of decomposing the statements like that. I will try it tomorrow morning. I've been changing this code a lot lately so I apologize that there are some inconsistencies between the cases. I hope the intent is clear. I will post the revised code after testing your idea.